# iOS chart library

Tags: ios, charts

I need to implement line chart with 2 colours like this:

[image]

So positive values should be blue and negative red and this is very important. Could u suggest iOS library to do this? I've already seen [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts), [PNChart](https://github.com/kevinzhow/PNChart) but they can't draw 2 coloured lines.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Any chance to draw 2 different lines? Pass only positive values to the first one and only negative ones to the second, like this it looks like just one line.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to subclass the `LineChartRenderer` in Charts, you would be able to use a mask on the bottom half of the screen when rendering the lines.

Basically create a new transparent `CGContext`, call `super` to draw the lines on it, mask it with `CoreGraphics`, then copy it on the original `CGContext`.

Answer (score 0):

That isnt a problem, when zu seperate **each** colored part in a own dataset and append it to the datasets arrays of the charts.
This results in 4 blue and 4 red datasets which you must add in an array and set it to the chart data.

some example from my project

```
var dataSets = [LineChartDataSet]()
// create different datasets
let dataSet = createDataSet(with: entries)
dataSets.append(dataSet)
```

Result with example values:
[image]